# Detect language of string from Google API C#

Tags: c#

i am trying to detect what language the written txt of player.LastChat is, and i am having some difficulties.

Here's the code i have:

```
String[] words = player.LastChat.Trim().Split(new Char[]{' ','\t',',','.',':','!','?',';','(',')',']','[','"'});
StringBuilder edited = new StringBuilder();
// Remove exception list words from line
foreach (String w in words) {
    if (plugin.isInList(w, "good_words")) {
        continue;
    }
    edited.Append(w);
    edited.Append(" ");
}

// URL Encode edited string
String UnreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";
StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();
String Input = edited.ToString();

for (int x = 0; x < Input.Length; ++x)
{
    if (UnreservedChars.IndexOf(Input[x]) != -1)
        Result.Append(Input[x]);
    else
        Result.Append("%").Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)Input[x]));
}
String key = "API KEY";
// Test for badness
bool jsonresult = false;

try {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    String json = client.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=" + key + "&q=" + Result.ToString());
    jsonresult = json.Contains("en");
} catch (Exception e) {
    plugin.ConsoleWrite("Language check failed! Error: " + e);
}
if (!jsonresult) {
    return true;
}
plugin.ConsoleWrite("Language: " + jsonresult);
return jsonresult; // for Actions
```

So, what i am trying to achieve, is to return true if it is any other language than "en" (english), but it is returning true no matter what.

The response from google is this:

```
{
"data": {
"detections": [
[
{
"language": "en",
"isReliable": false,
"confidence": 0.03396887
}
]
]
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, and i have no idea how to code, this code is borrowed from another script.

Regards.

Comment: Are you testing it with random strings or with actual sentences of foreign languages? The answers from Google basically says "In reality I have not any idea which could be this language, so I will default to English" (because English in incomprensible anyway, I guess :-p)

Comment: the jsonString.Contains("en") is not good, it will always return true because it will also find the "en" in "confidence", better to parse/deserialize it and get the value of language

Comment: @SJuan: I am testing with actual sentences from within the server i am running the script. :)

Comment: @Gunther34567: That's what i thought, and as i said i have no idea how to code, i just understand the logic. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make method work as described, you should change:

```
if (!jsonresult) {
    return true;
}
plugin.ConsoleWrite("Language: " + jsonresult);
return jsonresult;
```

to:

```
plugin.ConsoleWrite("Language: " + jsonresult);
return !jsonresult;
```

also this line

```
jsonresult = json.Contains("en");
```

is checking for any occurance of `"en"` in json text (and is found in `"confidence"` in your json). What you should do, is to parse Json using json.net (or other lib), or simply do this (but is an ugly hack):

```
jsonresult = json.Contains("\"language\": \"en\",");
```

Comment: Thank you! That works! I can add more languages now, and it returns true only if they are not the defined ones. :)